# Vue 2 dynamic input validation and character limitting

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can validate the user inputs on this input that is dynamically rendered roughly 30 separate times,

```html
<form>
  <div class="pseudo_table">
    <div class="table_div" v-for="(item, index) in inputArray" v-if="index > 0 && index <= 30">
      <p class="header thead">Year {{ index }}</p>
      <input class="interest_input" type="number" maxlength="6" v-model="inputArray[index]" />
      <label for="table_input" class="static_value">%</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Below you can find a picture of the code thats pasted in the side scroll above. With the added buttons that are mentioned later in the story.

[image: form]

As you can see I am rendering with v-for and have set a maxlength of 6 but since this a number type input the maxlength does not work.

I added a watch option but this actually doesn't work in real time and isn't doing anything to limit character length in the input. Further I would like to limit the range at which an input number can reach. If the number being entered is x.xxx greater than the old value it should show an error as well as disable the `save & continue` button.

```js
watch: {
  inputArray(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal - oldVal > this.settingsAssumptions.indexAverageAnnualIncrease) {

    }
    if (oldVal - newVal > this.settingsAssumptions.indexAverageAnnualDecrease) {

    }
    if (newVal.toString().length > 6) {
      parseFloat(newVal.slice(0, 6)).toFixed(3)
    }
  }
}
```

disabling the save and continue button is likely one of the easier things I can implement but I can't wrap my head around the watch functionality in the docs. Does anyone have any insight?

I've tried a suggestion made on another SO post that recommended using the `oninput` to validate the length and limit it in real time but unfortunately due to my inputs being `text-align:right`, when typing in the input field and adding a decimal, it will shift to the left of the number.

Comment: You can validate the input by using `:rules` attribute in your input field.

Comment: Yes please have a look and let me know if you will face any challenges in the implementation. I will be happy to help.

Comment: I am not finding any documentation on this rules attribute, is it available in vue 2?

Comment: Rohit might be referencing validating with Vuetify but I don't think you're using that library... Instead, you can call a validation method with an onInput event handler.  I'm not sure how you want to treat decimals which might change the code but [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-leavitt-shrvj8?file=/src/App.vue) should help.

Comment: ahh okay, that is correct I'm not using vuetify and not entirely sure if my parameters would allow me add an additional dependency. This does help and achieves my goal but main problem @yoduh my inputs are right aligned and for some reason that is causing the decimal to shift left of whatever numbers i input using the slice method.